# Transfer User data to a .csv file on my server

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, csv

I like to add user statistics to my apps.
I like to transfer the iOS version and the iDevice model to a .csv file on my server. I know how to get the iOS version and the model name but not how to write the data to a .csv file

get iOS version: `[UIDevice currentDevice]. systemVersion;`

get model name: `[UIDevice currentDevice]. model;`

Does any one know how to write the iOS system version to a csv file like this:

iPhone, 6.1

iPad, 5.1

iPod, 4.3

This is the code I am now using, but the String is not been written to the .csv file:

```
NSString *userinfopath = @"http://idoodler.de/userdata.csv";

    NSURL *userinfo = [NSURL URLWithString:userinfopath];


    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:userinfopath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: userinfopath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Route creato");
    }

    NSMutableString *writeString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",[UIDevice currentDevice]. model,[UIDevice currentDevice]. systemVersion];


    NSLog(@"writeString :%@",writeString);

    NSFileHandle *handle;
    handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: userinfopath ];
    //say to handle where's the file fo write
    [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
    //position handle cursor to the end of file
    [handle writeData:[writeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
- (IBAction)saveAsFileAction:(id)sender {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: [self dataFilePath] contents:nil attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Route creato");
    }

    NSMutableString *writeString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",[UIDevice currentDevice]. model,[UIDevice currentDevice]. systemVersion]; 


    NSLog(@"writeString :%@",writeString);

    NSFileHandle *handle;
    handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: [self dataFilePath] ];
    //say to handle where's the file fo write
    [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
    //position handle cursor to the end of file
    [handle writeData:[writeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}
```

Comment: My file is stored on my server, where must I how can I replace the fileparth with the URL?